# trouble writing to files in a loop

Tags: c++

I'm having problems getting this program work correctly. The program asks for a question and then writes that question to a file. Then it ask you if you want to enter another question. If you hit '1' it will loop and ask you to enter another a question. The program itself runs and closes without any issues. The problem is no matter how many questions I enter, it will only write the first question to file. The rest are replaced by blank lines. If I close the program and rerun it, it will, again, only write one line. I'm certain cin.ignore has something to do with it but I can't figure out how to fix it. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <limits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string question;
int x;


ofstream a_file("test.txt",ios::app);
    do
    {
        cout<<"Enter a question:\n\n";
        getline(cin,question);
        a_file<<question<<"\n";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout<<"Would you like to enter another question?\n";
        cout<<"1 for yes. 2 for no: ";
        cin>>x;

    }
    while (x!=2);

a_file.close();
cout<<"\nYour submition has been saved. Have a nice day!\n";
cout<<"Press enter to close the program.";
cin.ignore();
cin.get();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem associated with your code is here:

```
 cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

will ignore a whole line. then when you try to use `getline` to get the next line, you get nothing inside the while loop.

You can fix this as follows:(EDIT as pointed by Pablo)

```
do
{
    if (question.length() >0)
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin.clear(); 
    cout<<"Enter a question:\n\n";
    getline(cin,question);
    a_file<<question<<"\n";
    cout<<"Would you like to enter another question?\n";
    cout<<"1 for yes. 2 for no: ";
    cin>>x;
}while (x!=2);
```

I tried this fix will gcc 4.5.3, it worked well as expected. There should exist more elegant fix.

Comment: Is it just my compiler, or when I set option to ask another question with your code it skips it and siplays the menu again?

Comment: @PabloLemurr sorry, posted the wrong code, just updated the post. press enter when it run since the first line is ignored. ugly fix

Comment: There is a fix... For this fix :D
`if (question.length() > 0) cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Kids, don't try this at home.

Comment: @tacp I tried your suggestion and compiled it in codelite and g++. Every time I select '1' after my input, it skips the input part of the loop and takes me back to "would you like to enter another question?". My guess is something from my previous input is still stuck in the buffer and is being passed as input the next time I go through the loop. That was why I put cin.ignore(numeric_limits). I was unable to compile in gcc, I got a bunch of errors.

Comment: @Darkc0de Weird, we tried it worked fine. could you post you updated code here: http://liveworkspace.org/  and send me the link so I can take a look?

Comment: @PabloLemurr I tried your "if statment" suggestion and I still takes me back to the menu. Is it working on your compiler? Maybe the problem is my compiler?

Comment: @Darkc0de - It's good to be lazy and I didn't close the project. Yes, it works, even after re-copypasting the code. I suggest deleting the `test.txt`, and all of your output `*.o` files.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. I appreciate the help. I'll your suggestion a try. I'm waiting for my confirmation email from liveworkspace.org and if I still have problems I will post it there.

Comment: @PabloLemurr Your suggestion worked! The problem was I had the if statement and cin.ignore in the wrong place. I copied and pasted the code above and it worked. I've been stumped for over a week on this. You guys are geniuses! Thanks! :D

Comment: @Darkc0de - accept the answer, give upvotes... And remember, that the simplest solution is the best, even if it's hard to find it ;)